# Keep getting errors when sending emails using exim4

Tags: server, email

I think I've pulled out the rest of the hair I have.  I currently have a CentOS machine that I am moving everything to Ubuntu.

My biggest holdback is email.  I have exim4 on both machines.  I could probably copy the config file from the CentOS machine to Ubuntu but I really need to start fresh.

I have local emails working however, when I send emails to remote domains I get the following error: Mailing to remote domains not supported.

I wanted to use the regular exim4 config however, with all of the various parts, it can become a little daunting for this novice.  I took the compiled config file and changed it to exim4.conf and made a number of changes.  The file is included below.  Can someone tell me how I can send the config file?  Every time I try to, I get an error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "*The file is included below*" - no such file exists? nor any link to a file where we can view it.  The text following that makes no sense, or are you *narrating* or *asking* us another question about providing that file?  It's unclear due to formatting & text.

Comment: Sorry, I tried multiple times including the file in this post and every time it thinks it's spam and won't include it.  Is there any way I can include it?  I have it as a text file that I can copy and paste.

Comment: Upload it to a site, and provide the URL where readers can view it.

Comment: Thank you... I will do so either this evening or tomorrow morning and provide a link to the file.

Comment: Ok, I was able to upload the config file to dropbox.  Here's the link to that file:  https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ijlel92jn99gjst4k8sjt/putty.txt?rlkey=zyfsp3smh5uzbq5bikvc2tzqv&dl=0

Thank you in advance.  Very much appreciated.

Comment: Hello, was anyone able to take a look at this and tell me where I went wrong?